# Add comma after object value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am trying to get a result like the following in order to call a SQL query. It's an array of objects (each object with a key, that's going to be `VALUE` and a value. The value must be into single quotes with a comma at the end):

```
[
  { VALUE: 'A', },
  { VALUE: 'B', },
  { VALUE: 'C', },
  { VALUE: 'D', },
  { VALUE: 'E', },
  { VALUE: 'F' }
]
```

I've tried using a for function in which I add an object for each element in a list. This is the result I get:

Code:

```
    let arr = [];
    const len = reqBody.values.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        arr.push( { VALUE: reqBody.values[i] } )
    }
```

Result:

```
[
  { VALUE: 'A' },
  { VALUE: 'B' },
  { VALUE: 'C' },
  { VALUE: 'D' },
  { VALUE: 'E' },
  { VALUE: 'F' }
]
```

I've tried using a `map` arrow function with a `join` at the end of it in order to try to add the comma after each value (so for the second line of the result code would be something like: `{ VALUE: 'A', }`) but I cant make it work since that returns an array of strings, not objects like the ones I need.

This is the code described above:

Code:

```
let arr = [];
const len = reqBody.values.length;

for (let i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    arr.push(Object.values({ VALUE: reqBody.values[i] }).map(v => `{ VALUE: '${v}', }`).join(','))
}
```

Result:

```
[
  "{ VALUE: 'A', }",
  "{ VALUE: 'B', }",
  "{ VALUE: 'C', }",
  "{ VALUE: 'D', }",
  "{ VALUE: 'E', }",
  "{ VALUE: 'F', }",
]
```

Is there any way to cast that string in the map function to be an object?

Comment: Why would you need this? If the database column is supposed to contain JSON, the extra comma is not valid there.

Comment: This sounds like a textbook [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to construct the entire thing as a concatenated string, not as an array.

```js
let reqBody = {
  values: ['A', 'B', 'C']
};

let items = reqBody.values.map(v => `{ VALUE: '${v}', }`);
let result = '[\n  ' + items.join(',\n  ') + '\n]';
console.log(result);
```